# For all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and an arbitrary $b\in\mathbb{R}$, ${}_2F_1(a,b,b,z)=(1-z)^{-a}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, hypergeometric-function

The Gaussian hypergeometric function is given by:
$${}_2F_1[a,b,c,z]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(a)_n(b)_n}{(c)_n n!}z^n,$$
where $(a)_n=a(a+1)\dots(a+n-1)$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $(a)_0=1$, is the Pochammer symbol.

If $|z|<1$, we easily obtain that ${}_2F_1[a,b,b,z]=(1-z)^{-a}$. If $|z|>1$, we can use the transformation:
$$ {}_2F_1[a,b,c,z]=\dfrac{(-z)^{-a}\Gamma(c)\Gamma(a-c)}{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(b-a)} {}_2F_1[a,a-c+1,a-b+1,1/z]+\dfrac{(-z)^{-b}\Gamma(a-b)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(c-b)\Gamma(c)} {}_2F_1[a,b-c+1,b-a+1,1/z] $$
taking $c=b$ and keeping in mind that $\lim_{n\to0}\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(n)}=0.$ My question is, what to do in the case $|z|=1$? Or is there an analytic continuity argument to justify equality for any $z$?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: $(1-z)^{-a}$ is not well defined for all complex $z$ except when $a=0,-1,-2,\ldots$.

Comment: This is true, we then suppose that $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$. How can we see that the identity is valid for $|z|=1$? On the other hand, if we use Mathematica, for example, the equality is valid for all value of $z$.

Comment: You should suppose that $z\in \mathbb{C} \setminus [1,+\infty)$. Then you need to define the hypergeometric function analytically outiside the unit circle in the above domain. Then the result follows by the uniqueness property of analytic functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hypergeometric function $F (a, b; c; z)$ is defined by
the Gauss series for $|z| < 1$ and by analytic continuation elsewhere (notably using Mellin-Barnes integrals; by using the hypergeometric transformation you mention for |z| > 1, you are actually performing a certain kind of analytic continuation; others exist).

In the special case $c=b$ you are mentioning, $(1-z)^{-a}$, when defined itself, is an analytic continuation of the Gauss hypergeometric function in the whole complex plane, except for $z\in [1,+\infty[$, which is a branch cut. You will have to choose a principal branch of the power function to work this out cleanly, unless $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, see NIST 4.2. So this simple continuation in particular works for $|z|>1, z\notin \mathbb{R}$ too without resorting to the hypergeometric transformation you mention in the post. Finally this transformation is only useful for real values of $z>1$.

Therefore there only remains to consider the special case $z=1$, for which two subcases arise.

**Subcase 1**

Either $a$ or $b$ is $0$ or a negative integer. Then the Gauss function reduces to a polynomial equal to the constant 1, if either $a=0$ or $b=0$, or of degree $|a|$ (resp. $|b|$), if $a$ (resp. $b$) is the only integer, or of degree $\min(|a|,|b|)$ if both are. In this case the value in 1 is trivially defined.

It so happens that this value has an elegant closed form. If $a=-n, n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, and $c$ is not $0$ or a negative integer, then
$$F (−n, b; c; 1) = \frac{(c-b)_n}{(c)_n}$$(NIST 15.4.24),
where $(\;)_n$ is the Pochhammer symbol, this formula being known as the Chu-Vandermonde identity. Note that when $b=c$,

$$F (−n, b; b; 1) = \frac{(0)_n}{(b)_n} = 0$$

a result that is not entirely trivial from the definition of the Gauss function as a power series.

**Subcase 2**

Neither $a$ nor $b$ is $0$ or a negative integer.

The Gauss hypergeometric function has a branch cut in the complex place in the interval $[1, +\infty[$. For $z=1$ its possibly defined value are well-known to be conditional on parameters $a,b, c$.

They are given by tabulated formulae in NIST and other such reference books:

$$\text{If }\; \Re(c − a − b) > 0, \text{then }\; F (a, b; c; 1) = 
\frac{Γ(c) Γ(c − a − b) }{Γ(c - a)Γ(c - b)}$$

(NIST 15.4.20) provided that $c-a$ and $c-b$ are not $0$ or negative integers (this formula is sometimes referred to as Gauss's hypergeometric theorem).

In particular when $c=b$ (or $c=a$), there is no defined value as $\Gamma(0)$ is not defined. You may however define it as a zero limit resulting from Gauss's theorem, provided that $\Re{a} < 0$ (otherwise there is a ratio of two infinities in Gauss's theorem). *Mathematica* and most software I know of follow this convention.

Otherwise values may only be defined as limits of equivalent functions when $z \to_{1-}$, check NIST 15.4.21-15.4.23.

---

**Reference**

*National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST) Handbook of Mathematical Functions*, Frank W. J. Olver, Daniel W. Lozier, Ronald F. Boisvert, Charles W. Clark, Cambridge University Press, 2010.